# How to put a file .sql which is in s3 in a db on aws?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a .sql file in an s3 bucket. how can I send the dumps in a db as fast as possible on aws?

Comment: It seems that you are asking how to execute a MySQL `.sql` file against an existing database. Is that correct? Where is your database running? (eg on Amazon RDS, on an Amazon EC2 instance, on your own computer, etc)

Comment: Yes absolutely. I can have one running on Amazon RDS. Do you have a good way to put the dumps in it? Or if you have an efficient solution on an EC2 instance it can also be good. I tried the "restor-from-s3" aws button unsuccessfully. Thanks for your answer